# Why does this snippet of code return one answer but sometimes two?

Tags: python

New Python programmer here.  I'm trying to make a rock, paper, scissors game and I'm wondering why this code returns usually one answer but sometimes two.  I'm trying to make it print one answer for `choices1` and one for `choices2`.

Many thanks in advance :)

```py
from random import randint
    


choices1 = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']
choices2 = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']

if randint(0,3) == 0:
    print(choices1[0])

elif randint(0,3) == 1:
    print(choices1[1])

elif randint(0,3) == 2:
    print(choices1[2])


pass


if randint(0,3) == 0:
    print(choices2[0])

elif randint(0,3) == 1:
    print(choices2[1])

elif randint(0,3) == 2:
    print(choices2[2])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're generating a new random number every time you call `randint`.  What you want to do is generate a random number once and then do your `if`/`elif` checks.

```py
result = randint(0,2)
if result == 0:
    print(choices1[0])
elif result == 1:
    print(choices1[1])
else:
    print(choices1[2])
```

In fact, you're repeating code here.  A simpler solution would be

```py
result = randint(0,2)
print(choices1[result])
```

As pointed out in the comments, you can even skip generating the index altogether and use the `choice` function provided by the `random` module:

```py
result = random.choice(choices1)
print(result)
```

There are a few other issues.  First, you're generating a number between 0 and 3, inclusively, but your arrays only have indices going up to 2.  Second, you've got a `pass` statement in the middle of nowhere.  `pass` does nothing and is only needed in situations where you're required to have at least one line of code.  Third, there's no reason to have two separate lists, `choices1` and `choices2`, which contain the exact same values.

Putting everything together,

```py
choices = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']

result1 = random.choice(choices)
result2 = random.choice(choices)

print("Player 1's result is", result1)
print("Player 2's result is", result2)
```

Comment: Even simpler: `print(random.choice(choices1))` (and maybe just name the `list` `choices`; there's no reason to define two identical `list`s just to select from each separately); they just want the value, so they can select from it directly without generating an index and needing to ensure it matches the bounds of the sequence being selected from.

Comment: Nice answer (+1), to make it complete maybe provide a snippet to show how to generate the two choices for each player? I would also use `random.choice`.

Comment: Thank you very much to everyone for your answers, the addition of .choice is helping me a lot - I can move on to making this work now

Answer (score 1):

Since you are choosing one element from an array of elements, it would also make sense to define a function that randomly picked an element from an array.
That way, you can do something like:

```
def choose_one(...)

first = choose_one(choices1)
second = choose_one(choices2)
```

It turns out, this is handy enough of a function to make it to the standard API, to:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice

So your code could be as simple as:

```py
from random import choice

choices1 = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']
choices2 = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']

print(choose(choices1))
print(choose(choices2))
```

Answer (score 0):

you are calling `randint()` function again and again in the if else block. So, sometimes, it is giving two results and some times, it is giving single result. Also, you are calling `randint(0,3)`, which will give values between 0 and 3. But, your if/else statment will not match when 3 is returned. you have to modify code as `randint(0,2)`.

For getting two results always, you have call them initially and store the values. Use the stored value subsequently.

```py
from random import randint
    


choices1 = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']
choices2 = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']

selectedChoice1 = randint(0,2)
selectedChoice2 = randint(0,2)


if selectedChoice1 == 0:
    print(choices1[0])

elif selectedChoice1 == 1:
    print(choices1[1])

elif selectedChoice1 == 2:
    print(choices1[2])


pass


if selectedChoice2 == 0:
    print(choices2[0])

elif selectedChoice2 == 1:
    print(choices2[1])

elif selectedChoice2 == 2:
    print(choices2[2])
```